# Why does my Android Quiz App crash when submitting the answer & do not print the questions?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

My question is sort of double barrelled, I am developing a simple Quiz app using android studio. To me the code seems fine and there are no error messages being shown when I compile the app. However, when I run the app the Questions(strings) aren't displayed in the UI and when I hit the submit answer button the app just crashes. Below is a sample of the code I am implementing. Any help or advice will be greatly appreciated. Thank you

```
package com.example.shaun.quiz;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public int currentQuestion;
    public String[] questions;
    public String[] answers;

    Button answerButton;
    Button questionButton;
    public TextView questionView;
    public TextView answerView;
    public EditText answerText;

    public void main() {
        questions = new String[]{"1+2= ?", "1+1= ?",};     /*Array of Hard Coded Questions*/
        answers = new String[]{"3", "2",};                 /*Array of Hard Coded Answers to indexed to match the questions*/
        currentQuestion = -1;                              /*This will index the questions to be used*/
        answerButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.AnswerButton);
        questionButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.QuestionButton);
        questionView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.QuestionTextView);
        answerView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.AnswerTextView);
        answerText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.AnswerText);

        answerButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                checkAnswer();
            }
        });

        questionButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                showQuestion();
            }
        });
    }

    public void showQuestion() {
        currentQuestion++;
        if (currentQuestion == questions.length)
            currentQuestion = 0;
        questionView.setText(questions[currentQuestion]);
        questionView.setText("");
        answerText.setText("");
    }

    public boolean isCorrect(String answer)
    {
        return (answer.equalsIgnoreCase(answers[currentQuestion]));
    }


    public void checkAnswer()

    {
        String answer = answerText.getText().toString();
        if(isCorrect(answer))
            answerView.setText("Correct!");                                               /*answerView, text view set to print the string in the event of the correct answer*/
        else
            answerView.setText("Sorry, the Correct answer is "+answers[currentQuestion]); /*answers[currentQuestion] answers reads the answer to the current question in use */
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        main();
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome, you could add the stacktrace of this crash. These are really useful

Comment: PS : in showQuestion, you set the question text then clean it (and you don't call the method on create, only on click). And remove the empty cells in your arrays (the last `,`)

Comment: remove `questionView.setText("");` to make your question visible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never call the methods `showQuestion()` (unless from the button) so the index `currentQuestion` is still to -1 when the Activity is created.

So when you check the answers, you are trying to access `answers[-1]` leading to a [ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.html). You should call `showQuestion()` at the end of `main()` to show the first question and incrementing the `currentQuestion` to be in the bounds of the array.

PS : And you should removed `questionView.setText("");` in `showQuestion()` to show the text.

Answer (score 0):

You are clearing questionView textview from showQuestion() method. This is the reason why the question is not display.

And because of question not shown in it, and whenever you try to select answer, it just puts a `nullPointerException` as the question related to the answer doesn't exist at all.

Comment: The EDIT of @Swr7der is wrong, a call of `getText()` on an empty TextView will not return `null` but `""`